# Click and Get Rid of Placeholder, Blur and Add Placeholder Again

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
$(document.ready(function () {
    var input = $("input:text");
    // This is where I want to add an attribute that never changes.
    static var inputPlaceholder = input.attr("placeholder");
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        $(this).click(function () { 
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "")
        });
        $(this).blur(function () { 
            $(this).attr("placeholder", inputPlaceholder)
        });
    }
});
```

Basically, I want something universal that gets rid of the placeholder on click and gets rid of it on blur. (By universal, I mean for every text input I put on the page. I would like to know how to do so. The "static" in the code is not real; I put it in because I did not know the real method. Thanks.

-Zooza

Comment: [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: BTW if you want to make placeholder text disappear on focus then just use CSS http://jsfiddle.net/fcdcpxrr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide placeholder on focus instead after typing the firs character you can just use CSS:

```
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   opacity:0;
}
:focus::-moz-placeholder { 
   opacity:0;
}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   opacity:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fcdcpxrr/1/

As to your proposed jQuery-based solution: you don't need a static or constant, you could just store the old placeholder in another property on focus and restore on blur:

```
$(function(){
   $('input').on('focus', function(){
     this._placeholder = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
      this.placeholder = '';
   }).on('blur', function(){
     this.placeholder = this._placeholder;
   })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fcdcpxrr/2/

Comment: Thanks! I think the CSS method is simplest.